# Comparison of and finding sumthrough front end angular I want to compare that RecoveryAmount of brand is equal to the sum of all agent incentives

Tags: angular

```
{
   "Result":{
      "Date":"2022-09-01T00:00:00",
      "Brand":[
         {
            "BrandRecoveryId":9,
            "BrandId":1,
            "BrandName":" Entertainment",
            "RecoveryAmount":5000,
            "IsEditable":false,
            "Agents":[
               {
                  "AgentSaleId":31,
                  "AgentId":4,
                  "AgentName":"Unit Leader",
                  "JobDescriptionId":4,
                  "JobDescriptionName":"Unit Leader",
                  "Incentive":1000,
                  "IsEditable":false
               },
               {
                  "AgentSaleId":32,
                  "AgentId":3,
                  "AgentName":"Team Leader",
                  "JobDescriptionId":3,
                  "JobDescriptionName":"Team Leader",
                  "Incentive":750,
                  "IsEditable":false
               },
               {
                  "AgentSaleId":33,
                  "AgentId":5,
                  "AgentName":"Team Leader 2",
                  "JobDescriptionId":3,
                  "JobDescriptionName":"Team Leader",
                  "Incentive":750,
                  "IsEditable":false
               },
               {
                  "AgentSaleId":34,
                  "AgentId":1,
                  "AgentName":"Sale Agent",
                  "JobDescriptionId":1,
                  "JobDescriptionName":"Sales",
                  "Incentive":166.66667,
                  "IsEditable":true
               },
               {
                  "AgentSaleId":35,
                  "AgentId":6,
                  "AgentName":"Sale 2",
                  "JobDescriptionId":1,
                  "JobDescriptionName":"Sales",
                  "Incentive":166.66667,
                  "IsEditable":true
               },
               {
                  "AgentSaleId":36,
                  "AgentId":7,
                  "AgentName":"Sale 3",
                  "JobDescriptionId":1,
                  "JobDescriptionName":"Sales",
                  "Incentive":166.66667,
                  "IsEditable":true
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "BrandRecoveryId":8,
            "BrandId":2,
            "BrandName":"News",
            "RecoveryAmount":70000,
            "IsEditable":false,
            "Agents":[
               {
                  "AgentSaleId":37,
                  "AgentId":4,
                  "AgentName":"Unit Leader",
                  "JobDescriptionId":4,
                  "JobDescriptionName":"Unit Leader",
                  "Incentive":10500,
                  "IsEditable":false
               },
               {
                  "AgentSaleId":38,
                  "AgentId":3,
                  "AgentName":"Team Leader",
                  "JobDescriptionId":3,
                  "JobDescriptionName":"Team Leader",
                  "Incentive":7000,
                  "IsEditable":false
               },
               {
                  "AgentSaleId":39,
                  "AgentId":5,
                  "AgentName":"Team Leader 2",
                  "JobDescriptionId":3,
                  "JobDescriptionName":"Team Leader",
                  "Incentive":7000,
                  "IsEditable":false
               },
               {
                  "AgentSaleId":40,
                  "AgentId":1,
                  "AgentName":"Sale Agent",
                  "JobDescriptionId":1,
                  "JobDescriptionName":"Sales",
                  "Incentive":1866.6666,
                  "IsEditable":true
               },
               {
                  "AgentSaleId":41,
                  "AgentId":6,
                  "AgentName":"Sale 2",
                  "JobDescriptionId":1,
                  "JobDescriptionName":"Sales",
                  "Incentive":1866.6666,
                  "IsEditable":true
               },
               {
                  "AgentSaleId":42,
                  "AgentId":7,
                  "AgentName":"Sale 3",
                  "JobDescriptionId":1,
                  "JobDescriptionName":"Sales",
                  "Incentive":1866.6666,
                  "IsEditable":true
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "BrandRecoveryId":null,
            "BrandId":3,
            "BrandName":"BOL Digital",
            "RecoveryAmount":null,
            "IsEditable":true,
            "Agents":null
         },
         {
            "BrandRecoveryId":10,
            "BrandId":4,
            "BrandName":"Newspaper",
            "RecoveryAmount":2500,
            "IsEditable":false,
            "Agents":[
               {
                  "AgentSaleId":43,
                  "AgentId":4,
                  "AgentName":"Unit Leader",
                  "JobDescriptionId":4,
                  "JobDescriptionName":"Unit Leader",
                  "Incentive":500,
                  "IsEditable":false
               },
               {
                  "AgentSaleId":44,
                  "AgentId":3,
                  "AgentName":"Team Leader",
                  "JobDescriptionId":3,
                  "JobDescriptionName":"Team Leader",
                  "Incentive":375,
                  "IsEditable":false
               },
               {
                  "AgentSaleId":45,
                  "AgentId":5,
                  "AgentName":"Team Leader 2",
                  "JobDescriptionId":3,
                  "JobDescriptionName":"Team Leader",
                  "Incentive":375,
                  "IsEditable":false
               },
               {
                  "AgentSaleId":46,
                  "AgentId":1,
                  "AgentName":"Sale Agent",
                  "JobDescriptionId":1,
                  "JobDescriptionName":"Sales",
                  "Incentive":83.333336,
                  "IsEditable":true
               },
               {
                  "AgentSaleId":47,
                  "AgentId":6,
                  "AgentName":"Sale 2",
                  "JobDescriptionId":1,
                  "JobDescriptionName":"Sales",
                  "Incentive":83.333336,
                  "IsEditable":true
               },
               {
                  "AgentSaleId":48,
                  "AgentId":7,
                  "AgentName":"Sale 3",
                  "JobDescriptionId":1,
                  "JobDescriptionName":"Sales",
                  "Incentive":83.333336,
                  "IsEditable":true
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   "Count":null,
   "Message":"Success",
   "ErrorInternal":null,
   "StatusCode":200
}
```

Comment: I have an array of brand and in that array there is another array Agents.. while editing Incentives amount of agents I want to check the amounts enter is equal to the RecoveryAmount

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const result = {
   "Result":{
      "Date":"2022-09-01T00:00:00",
      "Brand":[
         {
            "BrandRecoveryId":9,
            "BrandId":1,
            "BrandName": "Entertainment",
            "RecoveryAmount":5000,
            "IsEditable":false,
            "Agents":[
               {
                  "AgentSaleId":31,
                  "AgentId":4,
                  "AgentName":"Unit Leader",
                  "JobDescriptionId":4,
                  "JobDescriptionName":"Unit Leader",
                  "Incentive":1000,
                  "IsEditable":false
               },
               {
                  "AgentSaleId":32,
                  "AgentId":3,
                  "AgentName":"Team Leader",
                  "JobDescriptionId":3,
                  "JobDescriptionName":"Team Leader",
                  "Incentive":750,
                  "IsEditable":false
               },
               {
                  "AgentSaleId":33,
                  "AgentId":5,
                  "AgentName":"Team Leader 2",
                  "JobDescriptionId":3,
                  "JobDescriptionName":"Team Leader",
                  "Incentive":750,
                  "IsEditable":false
               },
               {
                  "AgentSaleId":34,
                  "AgentId":1,
                  "AgentName":"Sale Agent",
                  "JobDescriptionId":1,
                  "JobDescriptionName":"Sales",
                  "Incentive":166.66667,
                  "IsEditable":true
               },
               {
                  "AgentSaleId":35,
                  "AgentId":6,
                  "AgentName":"Sale 2",
                  "JobDescriptionId":1,
                  "JobDescriptionName":"Sales",
                  "Incentive":166.66667,
                  "IsEditable":true
               },
               {
                  "AgentSaleId":36,
                  "AgentId":7,
                  "AgentName":"Sale 3",
                  "JobDescriptionId":1,
                  "JobDescriptionName":"Sales",
                  "Incentive":166.66667,
                  "IsEditable":true
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "BrandRecoveryId":8,
            "BrandId":2,
            "BrandName":"News",
            "RecoveryAmount":70000,
            "IsEditable":false,
            "Agents":[
               {
                  "AgentSaleId":37,
                  "AgentId":4,
                  "AgentName":"Unit Leader",
                  "JobDescriptionId":4,
                  "JobDescriptionName":"Unit Leader",
                  "Incentive":10500,
                  "IsEditable":false
               },
               {
                  "AgentSaleId":38,
                  "AgentId":3,
                  "AgentName":"Team Leader",
                  "JobDescriptionId":3,
                  "JobDescriptionName":"Team Leader",
                  "Incentive":7000,
                  "IsEditable":false
               },
               {
                  "AgentSaleId":39,
                  "AgentId":5,
                  "AgentName":"Team Leader 2",
                  "JobDescriptionId":3,
                  "JobDescriptionName":"Team Leader",
                  "Incentive":7000,
                  "IsEditable":false
               },
               {
                  "AgentSaleId":40,
                  "AgentId":1,
                  "AgentName":"Sale Agent",
                  "JobDescriptionId":1,
                  "JobDescriptionName":"Sales",
                  "Incentive":1866.6666,
                  "IsEditable":true
               },
               {
                  "AgentSaleId":41,
                  "AgentId":6,
                  "AgentName":"Sale 2",
                  "JobDescriptionId":1,
                  "JobDescriptionName":"Sales",
                  "Incentive":1866.6666,
                  "IsEditable":true
               },
               {
                  "AgentSaleId":42,
                  "AgentId":7,
                  "AgentName":"Sale 3",
                  "JobDescriptionId":1,
                  "JobDescriptionName":"Sales",
                  "Incentive":1866.6666,
                  "IsEditable":true
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "BrandRecoveryId":null,
            "BrandId":3,
            "BrandName":"BOL Digital",
            "RecoveryAmount":null,
            "IsEditable":true,
            "Agents":null
         },
         {
            "BrandRecoveryId":10,
            "BrandId":4,
            "BrandName":"Newspaper",
            "RecoveryAmount":2500,
            "IsEditable":false,
            "Agents":[
               {
                  "AgentSaleId":43,
                  "AgentId":4,
                  "AgentName":"Unit Leader",
                  "JobDescriptionId":4,
                  "JobDescriptionName":"Unit Leader",
                  "Incentive":500,
                  "IsEditable":false
               },
               {
                  "AgentSaleId":44,
                  "AgentId":3,
                  "AgentName":"Team Leader",
                  "JobDescriptionId":3,
                  "JobDescriptionName":"Team Leader",
                  "Incentive":375,
                  "IsEditable":false
               },
               {
                  "AgentSaleId":45,
                  "AgentId":5,
                  "AgentName":"Team Leader 2",
                  "JobDescriptionId":3,
                  "JobDescriptionName":"Team Leader",
                  "Incentive":375,
                  "IsEditable":false
               },
               {
                  "AgentSaleId":46,
                  "AgentId":1,
                  "AgentName":"Sale Agent",
                  "JobDescriptionId":1,
                  "JobDescriptionName":"Sales",
                  "Incentive":83.333336,
                  "IsEditable":true
               },
               {
                  "AgentSaleId":47,
                  "AgentId":6,
                  "AgentName":"Sale 2",
                  "JobDescriptionId":1,
                  "JobDescriptionName":"Sales",
                  "Incentive":83.333336,
                  "IsEditable":true
               },
               {
                  "AgentSaleId":48,
                  "AgentId":7,
                  "AgentName":"Sale 3",
                  "JobDescriptionId":1,
                  "JobDescriptionName":"Sales",
                  "Incentive":83.333336,
                  "IsEditable":true
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   "Count":null,
   "Message":"Success",
   "ErrorInternal":null,
   "StatusCode":200
};

result.Result.Brand.forEach(brand => {
  console.log('Name:', brand.BrandName);
  console.log('RecoveryAmount', brand.RecoveryAmount);
  console.log('Sum of Agent Incentive', brand.Agents?.reduce((acc, agent) => acc + agent.Incentive, 0));
});
```